# If event on specific Keypress

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I have a very simple -albeit frustrating- question today. I need to have an If statement that runs code only if the user has pressed a certain key. How do I do that? I have the Keypress sub already made:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClickField1.KeyPress
         If KeyPressed = Z Then
              'Run Code
         Else
               Return
         End If
```

What's the 'If KeyPressed = Z Then' proper syntax?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested out the code you guys gave me, and it works! Thanks again!

Comment: This question doesn't show enough research - how to do simple syntax is bread and butter vb.net and in the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, here's something for a start.

```
 If e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower.Equals("z") Then 'Both z and Z
            'Something
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The `e` parameter of the KeyPress event handler should be a `KeyPressEventArgs` object and not an `EventArgs` object. `KeyPressEventArgs` has a `KeyChar` property that contains the `Char` value that represents the key that was pressed.

If you want to check for uppercase "Z", you can use this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "Z"c Then
        'run code
    Else
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```